# Proper C preprocessor macro no-op

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

For debug logging, I have often seen and used something like

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define DLOG(fmt, args...) printf("%s:%d "fmt,__FILE__,__LINE__,args)
#else
    #define DLOG(fmt, args...)
#endif
```

but in a number of places, I have seen the second `#define` replaced with

```
#define DLOG(fmt, args...) do {} while (0)
```

In particular, there's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1306690/291280), and the comment on [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1306683/291280) to the same question suggests that the problem would be in a situation like

```
if (condition)
    DLOG("foo");
```

though my quick test suggests that the resulting semicolon on the line by itself will serve as the no-op statement inside the conditional.

Is one or the other of *nothing* and `do {} while (0)` better?  If so, why?  Is there something else that's even better?

Comment: possible duplicate of [do { ... } while (0) what is it good for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [C #define macro for debug printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing/1644898#1644898) for an explanation of why you want a different form of no-op.  You want to have the compiler parse the debug printing code even when you aren't using it so that errors do not creep in.

Answer (score 10):

A semicolon by itself has two drawbacks:

- Users of your macro can write it without a semicolon, and the compiler will not complain, and
- Some compilers may issue a warning about a possibly stray semicolon.

The `do {} while (0)` trick addresses both these concerns:

```
DLOG("foo") // No semicolon
```

will trigger an error, and the compiler will not warn you about a "stray" semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that the do/while method lets you have a multi-statement replacement and still use it as a single statement in an `if` case like you have in your question.  For a single expression replacement, I don't think there's any difference.