# Discard existing printf statements and enable newly added printf statements

Tags: c

I have many existing printf statements that I want to disable via:

```
#define printf(...) {};
```

But I want to define a new myprintf statement that will still use the stdio printf.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
#define myprintf (printf)
```

The parentheses will disable macro expansion.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define printf(...) do {} while(0)
#define myprintf (printf)

int main() {
  printf("printf\n");
  myprintf("myprintf\n");
}
```

(Not that I would recommend #defining `printf` away in the first place...)

For an explanation of why I've used `do {} while(0)` instead of `{}`, see [Proper C preprocessor macro no-op](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549193/proper-c-preprocessor-macro-no-op)

Comment: Fantastic...thanks! This is for debugging but I am interested in the dangers of #defining printf in the first place

Comment: The space in the `#define` line, between `myprintf` and `(`, is very important. If you instead wrote `#define myprintf(printf)`, then `myprintf` would be a macro that takes one argument and expands to nothing.

Comment: I don't think you need the `do ... while (0)` in this case. `#define printf(...)` should work, as long as no `printf` calls are used as operands. Another option is `#define printf(...) 0`